# Translation of rotated element

Tags: math, graphics, trigonometry

I have an object rotated around point (0,0). I can't change the anchor point. The rotation is done by another system and I can't influence that. All I have control of is the position of the element (and I can access the rotation value).
Now, I'd like to adjust the element position to make it appear like it's rotating around a specific pivot point.

How it is:
[image]

How I want it to be:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong (your description honestly isn't great) but it looks to me like you just want to have the anchor point (that you have no control over) in the center of your image.  So you just need to know the anchor point, and then calculate, probably, the top-left corner of your image based on the center of it being at the same point as the anchor.  If the anchor point is (a,b), the width and height of your image are w and h, respectively, then the top-left corner of your image should go at the point (a - w/2, b - h/2).  That is you need to subtract off half of both dimensions.